# How can we know the source of csv from github link

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe, csv, github

I'm new with github . Can somebody tell how can I retrace the csv link -
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv
to its source where it has been uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are 2 ways.**

**Method 1**

In the link you provided, **replace "raw.githubusercontent.com"** with **[www.github.com](http://www.github.com)**

**Method 2**

Another easy way to retrace this csv link would be to simply search it on [google.com](https://www.google.com)

1. Open [Google.com](https://www.google.com)
2. Search the exact link:
   "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv"
3. Look at the search results and guess and check.

In this case, the second result points to https://github.com/datasets/covid-19/blob/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv

If you open this link that you found, you will see the repository that the file is uploaded to. By clicking on "covid-19" beside the "master"/branch dropdown, you will see the entire repository.

Comment: Really Thank you so much! .I searched the gihub earlier and couldn't trace.Thanks